# command python yowsup-cli -c config ... not working on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, whatsapp, yowsup

I am working on sending messages from RasPi through Whatsapp. I have already installed `yowsup`.
I have completed with the registration process using the following commands, and have stored it in a config file:

```
python yowsup-cli registration --requestcode sms --phone 39xxxxxxxxxx --cc 39 --mcc 222 --mnc 10  
python yowsup-cli registration --register xxx-xxx --phone 39xxxxxxxxxx --cc 39
```

I am also able to send and receive messages from RasPi using the `yowsup` command-line client using the following command:

```
yowsup-cli demos --yowsup --config config
```

But when I type the following command:

```
python yowsup-cli -c config -w -s 39xxxxxxxxxx "Message"
```

I get the following error:

```
Available commands are  
demos  versions  registration
```

How can I directly send a message through a Python script, without going through the client?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't related to raspberry-pi.

The new [yowsup-cli 2.0](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/yowsup-cli-2.0) changed the command line interface, and now you should run instead:

```
python yowsup-cli demos -c config -s 39xxxxxxxxxx "Message"
```

Now, you mention that you want to send from python directly, but note that your command line `python yowsup-cli` is still going through the "client". If you want to send directly from your python script, follow the [yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup) tutorials and/or read the actual yowsup-cli code as example for usage.

Having all that said, yowsup has a bit to go in the way of documentation. I guess it's up to all of us to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

the new yowsup-cli 2.0 has improved and does'nt need -w anymore, well there is another python module which can help you to send messages using yowsup

> pywhatsapp 0.0.7